# Gridview columns not being set to width I enter

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, width, boundfield

I have two gridviews one displaying under the other one. Both gridviews are exactly the same, the only difference with the second gridview is I am not showing the header column. I have tried setting the widths to the exact same values in both gridviews but the columns are not matching up.

I have tried setting with width on the boundfield:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="A/C" SortExpression="Code" ItemStyle-Width ="120px"></asp:BoundField>
```

I have tried setting the width of the column:

```
gridview.Columns[0].ItemStyle.Width = 120;
```

I have tried setting the width of the cells:

```
foreach (TableRow row in gridview.Controls[0].Controls)
{
    row.Cells[0].Width = 120;
}
```

None of the above have worked. The second gridview width (last row in the image) is not displaying the same as the first gridview
[image]

First Grid:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" 
                            id="gvJobsPerMonth" 
                            CssClass="tblResults" 
                            OnItemDataBound="gvJobsPerMonth_OnItemDataBound" 
                            AllowSorting="true" 
                            OnSortCommand="gvJobsPerMonth_Sort" 
                            DataKeyField="ID" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
```

Second Grid:

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" 
                                    id="gvJobsPerMonthTotals" 
                                    CssClass="tblResults"
OnItemDataBound="gvJobsPerMonthTotals_OnItemDataBound" 
                                    AllowSorting="true" 
                                    OnSortCommand="gvJobsPerMonthTotals_Sort" 
                                    DataKeyField="ID" 
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                    ShowHeader="false" >
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
```

Both grids are using the same CSS classes. The only difference is ShowHeader="false" on the second grid. But even if I set this to true the columns are still showing as different widths

Comment: It looks like there is some padding and/or margin css property in the header that is causing this. If you take a screenshot, is the header with the text `A/C` 120 or wider. My guesst is it is wider. If so you know it's causes by css.

Comment: @VDWWD question updated to show html code of gridviews

Comment: @RezaAghaei question updated to show html code of gridviews

Comment: Please share the whole code to reproduce the problem. The code that you have already shared is not enough.

Comment: If your ShowHeader="false", why you used HeaderStyle? (In second Grid)

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this code for your second GridView:

```
<RowStyle Width="120px"/>
```

#### Instead of `120px`, use the desired pixel, just after column close `</Columns>`, like this:

```
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle Width="120px"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of a GridView is set with the ItemStyle Width property.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="language" HeaderText="language">
  <ItemStyle Width="500px" />
</asp:BoundField>
```